# Metric/parameters to compare length of polyline

Tags: distance, conflation

What would be a good metric to compare the length of two polylines?

A very naive approach would be to define a maximum delta which the two lines can differ.

I'm looking for more approaches. For example one that might also take a function over the length of the polyline as a parameter. Does anybody has algorithms/functions to share and has even evaluated parameters that work quite good?

Comment: Why do you need it for? For conflation (according to the keywords)? In that case, are you sure you want to compare the 'polyline length' and not simply the polylines?

Comment: @jul I'm reading up on GIS and conflation methods specifically and I am "collecting" metrics that can be used. While the Hausdorff distance is certainly a very good metric, I am also interested in more basic metrics.

Answer (score 3):

[Hausdorf distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance) has many fans. It gives very satisfying outcomes for line matching.

Comment: My question is not about the distance of two lines (Hausdorff, Frechét) but only about comparing the length.

Answer (score 2):

When comparing line length **fractal dimension** can/should be considered. (more info: http://www.geog.ubc.ca/courses/klink/gis.notes/ncgia/u47.html#OUT47.2.1)